# Can you upload an Azure Artifact to npmjs.org?

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I'm wondering if it is possible to publish an Azure Artifact, that I made, to npmjs.org.

I've already managed to connect to the feed that I've created but I want to publish the package to npmjs.org and make it open-source. I would think that it is possible since npmjs.org is just another feed that I would need to publish to but I can't find any documentation or articles on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **npmjs.org** is an external npm registry in Azure Devops. So you need to create an npm service connection in `Project Settings -> Service connections`.

[image]

Then in Azure Pipeline, you could use NPM task(Connect to the Service connection) to publish the artifact to the npmjs.org.

[image]

For more detailed info, you could refer to this doc about [Publish npm packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/npm?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).